# typescript: using variables declared externally

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've got an application that is migrated into typescript. In my index.html file I've got 2 files (actually, a lot more, but those are significant):

- static.js - which holds the declaration: `var staticData = {...};`, built automatically by `grunt-json` grunt task (nevermind what it does, it's just dynamically generated)
- app.js - which is the typescript source dumped into js.

There is .ts a file that is used to build the `app.js`, which has following content:

```
mp.core.CoreModule
.constant('CONFIG', staticData.config)
.constant('lodash', _)
```

It's just declaring angular constants. When I try to compile this typescript file, I get following error:

```
Running "typescript:app" (typescript) task
>> app/modules/core/coreModuleConfig.ts(2,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 's
taticData'.
>> app/modules/core/coreModuleConfig.ts(3,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name '_
'.
Warning: Task "typescript:app" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

I can understand the problem - typescript doesn't know what these variables are. The problem is that staticData is a js-file variable and I've got no idea how I can make those file cope with each other... Lodash' case is the same - it's loaded into the HTML as an external script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick solution is to use ambient definitions with an `any` type:

```
declare var staticData: any;
declare var _: any;
```

That will allow you to use those variables in any way you want in your TypeScript. From this, you could start building on type information for `staticData` if you wanted.

Note that for `_`, you can just include the `lodash.d.ts` definition file in your project. That already has all the type information for lodash defined for you. You can find that [here](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/lodash/lodash.d.ts).